# Unresolved external symbol error overloading operator+ template

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload the `'+'` operator for a class template but getting unresolved external symbol error calling it using the infix notation:

```
// In main.cpp

template<class T>
struct B
{
    B(T t) : t_(t) {}
    friend B operator+(B const &lhs, B const &rhs);
    T t_;   
};

template<class T>
B<T> operator+(B<T> const &lhs, B<T> const &rhs)
{
    return B<T>(lhs.t_ + rhs.t_);
}

int main()
{
    B<int> b = 1;
    b = operator+<int>(b, 2); // works but clunky syntax
    // b = b + 2; // LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
}
```

It works fine for regular non-templated classes so wondering if it is possible to achieve the same thing here.

I'm using Visual C++ 2015.

Comment: `friend B operator+(B const &lhs, B const &rhs);` is not a template declaration, however you defined one.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864102/why-is-friend-member-function-not-recognized-as-function-template-automatically

Comment: BTW, currently all members are `public`, so no need of `friend` ;-)

Comment: Understood. Thanks for help. If anyone else reading this, I also found http://web.mst.edu/~nmjxv3/articles/templates.html quite helpful.

Comment: The comment by @GeorgeSkelton pointing to the article on templates is a very good one. That article does a wonderful job explaining the issues/options in understandable detail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
friend B operator+(B const &lhs, B const &rhs);
```

is a non template function.

The simpler would be to define it `inline`:

```
template<class T>
struct B
{
    B(T t) : t_(t) {}
    friend B operator+(B const &lhs, B const &rhs)
    {
       return B(lhs.t_ + rhs.t_);
    }
    T t_;   
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b3a736a6894437b)

Else you have to declare all template friend

```
template <typename T> struct B;

template <typename T> B<T> operator+(B<T> const &lhs, B<T> const &rhs);

template<class T>
struct B
{
    B(T t) : t_(t) {}

    template <typename U>
    friend B<U> operator+(B<U> const &lhs, B<U> const &rhs);
    T t_;   
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f1a0383b2b66d64)

or just the specific one

```
template <typename T> struct B;

template <typename T> B<T> operator+(B<T> const &lhs, B<T> const &rhs);

template<class T>
struct B
{
    B(T t) : t_(t) {}
    friend B operator+<>(B const &lhs, B const &rhs);
    // Note the <>

    T t_;   
};

template<class T>
B<T> operator+(B<T> const &lhs, B<T> const &rhs)
{
    return B<T>(lhs.t_ + rhs.t_);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f31c8307b5b3ca0a)

Comment: Defining it inline works but I want to avoid that because my real class has a lot more stuff going on inside it. I see that I failed to define a template function, however I tried your solutions and in both cases get `C2678: binary '+': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'B<int>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`.

Comment: @GeorgeSkelton: I added links.

Comment: Ah ok I see what you mean thanks. But it still won't compile `b + 1` because it can't deduce `B<int>` from `int`. However a member function can make such a deduction. Is this just an inherent limitation of friend function?

Comment: A "limitation" of template. How to know which template build from `int` ? You know that only `B<int>` have correct constructor, but they might have specializations, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined it as a template inside the class.
The simplest solution is defining the function inside the class (inline):

```
template<class T>
struct B
{
    B (T t) : t_ (t) {}
    friend B operator+ (const B &lhs, const B &rhs)
    {
       return B (lhs.t_ + rhs.t_);
    }
    T t_;   
};
```